# Small background image css

Tags: html, css, background

I am having the following problem;

I am trying to incorporate an image to my webpage, this image needs to be centered and not "dragable"? Like when you click on it and it moves. So I decided to make a div:

```
<div id="products_logo"></div>
```

And a css file:

```
.products #products_logo{
    background: url('../img/shop.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

This is creating 2 images of a shopping cart, One in the original place (this is drag-able) the other in the center (not drag-able), Also while im here, Is it better to have div as a ID or a class? Could I get a re-direction to a page that clarifies the differences?

Thankyou!

Some more html as requested:

```
<div class="products">
      <div id="products_logo"></div>
        <h1>Our Products</h1>
        <div class="products_table">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td id="ti1">item1</td>
                    <td id="ti2">item2</td>
                    <td id="ti3">item3</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td id="ti4">item4</td>
                    <td id="ti5">item5</td>
                    <td id="ti6">item6</td>
                  </tr>
            </table>
        <div>
    </div>
```

sorry it looks messy, messed up the code tags abit.

Comment: Can you post more of your HTML? What you have here would work as expected - only one image and not accessible via mouse. I'm just wondering if you have it somewhere else you overlooked. For `ID` vs `Class`, ID is very specific and will override class attributes. You can find info on specificity using Google.

Think of it like this from less specific to most (generalization): Class -> ID -> Inline.

Comment: One thing I noticed, is that you don't have `width` or `height` set for your `#products_logo` div. You need to set that. Based on what you are posting, I don't see why you would see double still. You can remove the `.products` before the `#products_logo` in your CSS if you want. It's not needed. That may be causing the issue (probably not though).

Comment: I have a jsfiddle file here: http://jsfiddle.net/WnLSS/ The thing you suggested (.products) did not fix the problem :( EDIT: http://i.imgur.com/03SJwdo.png (webpage section)

Comment: Here's your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/WnLSS/1/  you had some other HTML errors (unclosed HTML tags). But as you can see, only one logo.

Comment: Do you have this live somewhere? I suspect something else is going on.

Comment: No I dont, I drop box it in a minute, But now my image has dissipated completely .-.

Comment: Problem solved,
.products #products_logo{
background-image:url('../img/shop.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
width:200px;
height:200px;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't really "rules" for when and where to use ids and classes. It's important to remember that classes can be referenced more than once and ids are unique can only be referenced (assigned) once.

Generally, `<div>` tags are used when creating structured layouts. ID's give the layout sections unique names.

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="content">

    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

You can target ids in css like this:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

Being that classes can be referenced (assigned) more than once, they're great for assigning the same style to multiple elements.

```
<ul id="main_navigation" class="navigation">
    <li>Nav links go here...</li>
</ul>

<ul id="secondary" class="navigation">
    <li>Secondary nav links go here...</li>
</ul>
```

Here is a resource for you: [An excellent analysis on IDs vs Classes](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Comment: Thanks, I never new you could use id's and classes, How would you reference the first example in a css file?

Comment: I added the answer to your question in my original answer :)

Answer (score 0):

A div as an ID is a identification for the div tag.  If you want to reference that div you will need a ID.  A class gives css styles to the div.

Here's how to add an image that's not dragable.  remove some of the extra properties you don't need

```
 <div class="header_pic" style="border: 0px solid green">

</div>
```

.header_pic
    {
    background-image:url('/images/home/main_img.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom left;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:965px;
    height:325px;
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    z-index:1;
    }